# A question I have for a solution to a problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

There is an unlimited supply of congruent equilateral triangles made of colored paper. Each triangle is a solid color with the same color on both sides of the paper. A large equilateral triangle is constructed from four of these paper triangles. Two large triangles are considered distinguishable if it is not possible to place one on the other, using translations, rotations, and/or reflections, so that their corresponding small triangles are of the same color.

Given that there are six different colors of triangles from which to choose, how many distinguishable large equilateral triangles may be formed? (The triangle figure looks like the triforce star).

One solution that caught my eye was as follows:

There are $6$ choices for the center triangle. Note that given any $3$ colors, there is a unique way to assign them to the corner triangles. We have $6$ different colors to choose from, so the number of ways to color the corner triangles is the same as the number of ways to arrange $6 - 1 = 5$ dividers and $3$ identical items. Therefore, our answer is $6 \binom{5 + 3}{3} = 6\binom{8}{3} = \boxed{336}$.

Explanation of the bijection by WIlliamgolly: Let $1,2,3,4,5,6$ be the colors, and WLOG assume that the middle triangle has a color of $6$. Now, the color bijection can be formed as follows: Pick the colors to the immediate right of a divider. If there is no color to the immediate right of a divider, then that color is $6$.

For example, ||$12345$| would represent the colors $1,1,6$ as the colors chosen. Note for any three colors, there is only one way to fix it on the triangle, thus forming our stars and bars bijection.

I thought this was a very clever solution, but then I thought, why could we not add one extra bar and count the number of solutions using stars and bars then? For instance, why not instead of $3$ bars, add $4$ bars alongside this bijection? So for instance, |$1,2,3$||$4$|$5$, would represent the colours $1,4,4,5$. So then the solution must be $\binom{5+4}{4}=\binom{9}{4}$. But this is obivously wrong, because if you take another solution:

((If two of our big equilateral triangles have the same color for their center triangle and the same multiset of colors for their outer three triangles, we can carry one onto the other by a combination of rotation and reflection. Thus, to make two triangles distinct, they must differ either in their center triangle or in the collection of colors which make up their outer three triangles.

There are 6 possible colors for the center triangle.

There are ${6\choose3} = 20$ possible choices for the three outer triangles, if all three have different colors.
There are $6\cdot 5 = 30$ (or $2 {6\choose2}$) possible choices for the three outer triangles, if two are one color and the third is a different color.
There are ${6\choose1} = 6$ possible choices for the three outer triangles, if all three are the same color.
Thus, in total we have $6\cdot(20 + 30 + 6) = \boxed{336}$ total possibilities),
we have the same answer. So why cannot I just add the other bar without the requirement that I have to fix it?

Sorry if this question sucks. Just a confused guy looking to be unconfused.

Comment: Presumably https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2006_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_8

Comment: Answering this question should reveal the flaw in the $\binom94$ method: which large equilateral triangle does $|1,2,3||4|5$ represent?

Comment: @MikeEarnest There is no starting triangle! What does |$1,2,3||4|5$ even mean if we don't have a "base" to work with? Thank you! Do you have any tips to avoid any silly errors of this sort? They would really help, considering I suck at counting.

Comment: Yes: sanity checks. Write out all the stars-and-bars strings, and the triangles they correspond to, making sure everything really is represented once. Make the problem smaller if necessary (i.e. two colors instead of six).

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "A question I have for a solution to a problem" tells nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm guessing point 1 is what you're wanting. Point 2 is written up just in case its a potential confusion.)

1. Your idea of "let's just choose 4 colors" doesn't work because the central triangle is "distinguished", whereas the other 3 triangles yield a unique solution no matter what the colors are.

As explicit examples,

- if the colors were $1-1-1-1$, then there is only 1 such triangle.
- If the colors were $1-1-1-2$, then there are 2 such triangles (corresponding to inner triangle being 2 or not).
- If the colors were $1-2-3-4$, then there are 4 such triangles (corresponding to what the inner triangle is).

While we have the sortof-double-counting correspondence in the sense that "the number of possible triangles from a set of numbers is equal to the number of distinct elements", this requires understanding/listing the number of each case in order to get at the true count. (IE Number of ways to get $ A-A-A-A, A-A-A-B, A-A-B-B, A-A-B-C, A-B-C-D.)

Note: Furthermore, the takeaway from this, is that if we wanted to do a "count the number of distinct elements in each multi-set configuration, and sum up across all configurations", then the distinguished element approach allows us to convert a $ \sum n \times \text{number of configurations with n elements} $ to a $ \sum 1 $ counting.

2. The default way to do stars and bars for this question is that we have 3 $ \star$ and 5 $ \mid $ which we want to arrange in order. (This is complicated by the fact that you used the bars not in the typical way.)
   Your example of $ \mid \mid 12345 \mid$ corresponds to the default setup of $ \star \star \mid \mid \mid \mid \mid \star$, from which the bijection to $ 1-1-6$ follows immediately from the default interpretation (as opposed to having to add a paragraph to explain the bijection).
   Hence, the answer (for this part) is truly $ {5 + 3 \choose 3 } = 56$.

---

Note:

- Your addition of one extra (your) $\mid$ results in us picking 4 numbers instead.
- This is one reason why it's helpful to revert to the standard terminology, so that you don't have to reinterpret what you're thinking of in terms of your new terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it by cases.  As you say, there are $6$ choices for the center.  The outside three can only be arranged in one order up to rotation and reflection.  There are $6$ cases with one color, $6\cdot 5=30$ for two because the colors are distinguished by which one there are two of, and ${6 \choose 3}=20$ with all three different.  In total that makes
$$6 \cdot (6+30+20)=336$$

Comment: どうも！ありがとうございました！

Comment: @combinatorialist46Carey2:  I don't know what that says.